# Automatic Unique Sequence Number

Tags: list

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to generate a unique sequence number in list library based on 2 different columns.  It is a 2013 SharePoint Site.

The list library is set-up for users to fill out information regarding a particular request, if the request is approved, I am trying to have the site generate a sequence number based on 2 list columns.  Below is an example:

```
Category     Type    Outcome
Operations   200     AOL-201
Operations   200     AOL-202
Engineering  200     AEL-201
Engineering  200     AEL-202
```

I was able to achieve this through Excel using this formula

```
(=IF(OR(D3=0,C3=0),"",CONCATENATE("A",LEFT(C3,1),"L-",LEFT(D3,1),TEXT(COUNTIFS(C$2:C3,C3,D$2:D3,D3),"00")))).
```

Any help that you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You can use calculated column with formula.

Or you can create one workflow over the list, which will add value in unique number column with your specified logic.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Workflow would be your way to go: On update of the item: Check if the status is "approved" and the "sequence" is empty. If so: calculate a new sequence-value and update the item.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to count list items but you can not count list items using calculated column or workflow. Are you able to use JavaScript? You can achieve this using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

One other option could be to use "ID" column in a calculated column. Example

=CONCATENATE(IF(ID>2,"AOL","AEL"),ID)

ID>2 can be replaced by any other formula

Output:

[image]